# jQuery change element which is loaded on vue js v-if

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js

How can I change the text of element which is loaded with vue js on v-if
Here is an example:

```
<div id="app">
    <div v-if="show == 'first'">
        <p>something</p>
    </div>
    <div v-else-if="show == 'second'">
        <p>something2</p>
    </div>
</div>

<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>

<script>
    let app = new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
            show: 'first'
        }
    })
</script>
```

And here is the jquery that changes the text:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        let hovers = JSON.parse('{!! $module->hoverBalloons->toJson() !!}')

        console.log(hovers) 

        let element = '';

        for(let hover of hovers) {
            element = $('input[name="'+hover.form_field+'"], select[name="'+hover.form_field+'"], textarea[name="'+hover.form_field+'"]')
            // Search for an input with the same name or id as the form_field
            if (element.length > 0) {
                let id = element.attr('id')
                $('label[for="'+id+'"]').text(hover.label)                   
            }
            else {
                element = $('input#'+hover.form_field + ', select#'+hover.form_field + ', textarea#'+hover.form_field)

                // If the element is radio button change the span next to it
                if (element.attr('type') == 'radio') {
                    element.next('span').text(hover.label)
                }
                else {
                    $('label[for="'+hover.form_field+'"]').text(hover.label)
                }
            }
        }

        $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip(); 
    })
</script>
```

The jQuery will not change anything in the example vue because I showed it just for example so the code is more simple. The actual code is a bit more complex but I wrote this just so you can get the idea. So the problem is that the jQuery won't change the elements which are loaded with the v-if directive. How can i make it change them? Note: I thought of v-show, but sadly is not an option in my case because of vue transitions and etc.

Comment: Why are you even using jQuery at all to do this, instead of rendering data into the template with interpolations by Vue?

Comment: @DecadeMoon the problem is that I will have to change every field and there are a lot of fields
that's why I go through the fields with for loop and change them dynamically.

Comment: But you should be mutating the state, and rendering the state to the view, instead of modifying the view directly.